# TypoScript TMENU doesn't build absolute Links

Tags: navigation, typo3, typoscript

i have a big problem and i don't know what is wrong on my TS.

At the first: I activate the baseURL in my config ts and the  Tag will be set correctly.
In the next step, i build the navigation menu.

```
lib.MyNavigation = HMENU
lib.MyNavigation{
        special = directory
        special.value.data = leveluid:1
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1

        NO{
            linkWrap = <span>|</span>
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="{field:tx_nav_id}">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            allStdWrap.insertData = 1
        }

        ACT <.NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li id="{field:tx_nav_id}" class="active">|</li>
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2{
        wrap = <ul class="sub-lvl-2">|</ul>
        NO{
            linkWrap = <span>|</span>
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
        }

        ACT < NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT{
            linkWrap = <span>|</span>
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li>|*|<li class="active">|</li>|*|<li class="last active">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
        }
    }

}
```

But this will create links like `<a href="en/en/yourPage">...</a>` and this is a problem. I need URLs like `<a href="**/**en/en/yourPage">...</a>`

For your information: I use RealUrl.
Have anyone a tip for me?

**EDIT: This is my config.ts :**

```
config {
    debug = 0
    admPanel = 0
    simulateStaticDocuments = 0
    xmlprologue = none
    doctype = html5
    removeDefaultCSS = 1
    removeDefaultJS = 1
    disablePrefixComment = 1
    tx_realurl_enable = 1
    renderCharset = utf-8
    htmlTag_langKey = en
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
    language = en
    locale_all = us_EN.UTF-8
    sys_language_uid = 0
    extTarget >
    meaningfulTempFilePrefix = 100

#   baseURL = 
    absRefPrefix = /


    htmlTag_stdWrap.override (
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="de" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="de" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="de" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="de" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 10 ]>   <html lang="de" class="ie10"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="de"><!--<![endif]-->
    )

    typolinkCheckRootline = 1
    typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1
    content_from_pid_allowOutsideDomain = 1




    RTE.default {
        disableAlignmentFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
        disableSpacingFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
        disableColorFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
        disableLayoutFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
        disableBordersFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `config.absRefPrefix`, and leave `config.baseURL` empty. The `absRefPrefix` is prepended to generated URLs, so it should achieve what you want.

Comment: I have tested it with baseURL and absRefPrefix - but nothing will change the result. My config ts added to my question above this answer.

Comment: The config should build links like `<a href="/en/en/yourPage">...</a>`, the first slash is the `absRefPrefix`. If you want to have an absolute link containing the domain, set `config.absRefPrefix` to `http://example.com/` or similar.